# O365 Powershell add alias domain to users of another specific domain script issue

Tags: powershell, office365

I'm trying to add an alias domain to specific users of another domain using powershell and ExchangeOnlineManagement.  The script shows that it appears to work, but the alias domain never seems to actually get added for the users.  Here is the script.

`connect-exchangeonline

Import-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement

$users = Get-Mailbox | Where-Object{$_.PrimarySMTPAddress -match "domain1.com"}

foreach($user in $users){ Write-Host "Adding Alias $($user.alias)@domain2.com"}
`

The prompt then shows this:

'Adding Alias user@domain1.com'

'Adding Alias anotheruser@domain1.com'

so it looks successful but nothing happens?
Any ideas?

thanks!
Doug

Answer (score 0):

found the solution:

```
$mailboxes = Get-Mailbox -ResultSize unlimited -RecipientTypeDetails UserMailbox -Filter {UserPrincipalName -like "*@domain1.com"}

foreach($mailbox in $mailboxes) {
$emailaddress = $mailbox.Alias + "@domain2.com"
Set-Mailbox -Identity $mailbox.Identity -EmailAddresses @{Add=$emailaddress}
```

}